# DCT of a rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, rotations, signal-processing

Let's denote $C$ the DCT matrix and $A$ a rotation matrix (dimension is $n \times n$). The DCT of matrix $A$ is computed as follows:
$$CAC^{T}$$

C is an orthogonal matrix, thus the DCT of $A$ is still a rotation matrix. Simply put, what the DCT does is compressing the information contained in a matrix. What I don't get is an interpretation of what it does to a rotation matrix, and how it 'compresses' it. It still remains a rotation matrix, but then what does it really change ? And what does the IDCT do as well then ?

Comment: What does "DCT" mean??

Comment: Discrete Cosine Transform, sorry forgot to mention it.

Comment: Why would it have to compress it? Isn't it just a subset of the $n \times n$ matrices (viz. images) that are compressed well by the DCT?

Comment: So the fact that the DCT compresses matrices is true only true to certain types of matrices ? I thought it was a general property of the DCT, and that it would work for all matrices, but my knowledge on DCT is limited so I don't know. Anyway, in my case, the matrix A is a feature representing some recorded speech.

Comment: Yes, not all matrices will be compressed by the DCT. An example of something that won't compress is fullband noise. Optical images tend to have the majority of their energy concentrated at a small percentage of DCT samples because the objects we (i.e., humans) see at those wavelengths are smooth(ish) (low frequency energy) and not one edge after another (high frequency energy). As for the rotation matrix, you said yourself that it is still a rotation matrix, so I am not sure what you are asking.